# find the points on curve that are almost equal

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

How do I find the points pointed by the arrow in the graph. I.e. the points where the slope of curve is almost $0$.

Comment: What is the context of this question (are you familiar with calculus)? Do you have any thoughts on how we can approach the problem?

Comment: One thing you could try is to approximate, at each point $x_i$,  the value of the derivative using forward, backward or central differences.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for values of $x$ at which the slope $f'(x)$ has a local maximum. If the function is second-differentiable, then a necessary condition for $x$ to be such a point is that $f''(x)=0$.